# JavaFx how to avoid window freezing/not responding when running thread like api

Tags: java, api, javafx

When I tried to post to an API which is inside on the thread and run it, the whole window freezes even if I put the thread on the other window. What I want is even the thread is running I want to access the window. How to solve this problem ?. 
Here is my sample code:

```
public void method() {
    Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit(() -> {
      service.runService();
    });
  }
```

Comment: While you _appear_ to be executing the work on a separate thread you don't show enough code to be sure. Please [edit] your question to provide a [mre] demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved!
I used

```
asynctask
```

can be found here -- > https://github.com/victorlaerte/jfx-asynctask?source=post_page-----26689f3cd8fa----------------------

Comment: Instead of using newSingleThreadExecutor, I used asynctask